# Snowflake SQL finding each users Monthly login events from daily login events

Tags: sql, database, analytics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table of daily user logins

[image]

I need to write a query that will display the following monthly logins by each user as shown below:

The query I have is ... (***BUT THIS GIVES ME DUPLICATE ROWS AND INCORRECT COUNTS***)

```
select 
TO_DATE(Timestamp), 
User,
count(Transactions) over (partition by User)
from
(
//(0)
select Timestamp, User, Transactions 
from
MyTable
where
Transactions = 'Login' and
event_timestamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-31' 
order by Timestamp, User 
)
```

[image]

Appreciate any help in putting together the right query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is basically an aggregation query:

```
select user, date_trunc('month', timestamp), count(*), 
from MyTable
where Transactions = 'Login' and
       event_timestamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-31' 
group by user, date_trunc('month', timestamp)
order by user, min(timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff! One more question -  If I had a last column "session length" in the daily transaction table, what would the updated  query be to add a average session_length column in the monthly table?

Comment: @CoolDocMan . . . I think `avg(session_length)`.